# jQuery sortable rows and columns grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

Im trying to create a sortable grid using jQuery sortable. Here is my html:

```
<div id ="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="inner"> 1 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="inner">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="inner">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="inner">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="inner">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is javascript:

```
$("#container").sortable();
$("#container .inner").sortable({connectWith: ".column"});
```

I want to be able to sort rows as well as individual columns. Sorting rows works fine but for some reason nothing happens with columns. The idea is to move "inner" elements freely in any column.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be assuming that Sortable makes a grid for you. It does not.
Also, if you look at the sample, you will see two distinct containers for each column. I made a very simple one from divs and uses css to make it look like two columns. I assume that you will have the need includes in place.

if I saved it right, you should be able to see it work https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/f2pcc9wL/

```
<style>
    .container{ width:60px}
    .col1{ width:20px; 
         float:left;  }
    .col2{ width:20px; float:right}
    .cell{width:15px; border: thin solid black}
</style>
<script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#box1, #box2"  ).sortable({connectWith: '.both'})} );
</script>
<div class='container'>
    <div id='box1' class='col1 both'>
        <div class='cell'>1</div>
        <div class='cell'>2</div>
        <div class='cell'>3</div>
    </div>

    <div id='box2' class='col2 both'>
        <div class='cell'>4</div>
        <div class='cell'>5</div>
        <div class='cell'>6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```